# Retrieve Campaign by Its Name

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, campaign

Is it possible to retrieve Campaign(s) by its name with a REST API call? The documentation only specifies retrieving a campaign by its ID. Does anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like it's not possible - if you haven't got too many Campaigns you could retrieve all the campaigns and perhaps check for the name in the array or sync them to your own database for processing later?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getCampaignCollection.htm